# ShellExecute equivalent in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, windows-shell, shellexecute

I'm looking for the .NET-preferred way of performing the same type of thing that ShellExecute does in Win32 (opening, printing, etc. for arbitrary file types).

I've been programming Windows for over 20 years, but I'm a complete newbie at .NET, so maybe I'm just looking in the wrong places. I'm currently using .NET 2.0 (VS C# 2005), but could use VS 2008 if need be.

If the only answer is to use P/Invoke, then I might be better just writing my small utility using Win32 anyway.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx).

Note that advanced uses (printing etc) require using a [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo_properties.aspx) and setting the [Verb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verb.aspx) property.

Comment: (There is a bool property 'UseShellExecute' on it.)

Answer (score 44):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(command)
```

I bet you had trouble finding it because it is in the System.Diagnostics namespace.  "Diagnostics"?  Usually with 20 years experience one thing you get good at is guessing at what something will be called in a new API/language, but this one tricked me.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()`?

It's more or less similar to *ShellExecute*. You can open exes, documents. I haven't checked printing yet, Marc has told you how already.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the original Win32 `ShellExecute()` docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea

This C# code will work to open a web browser tab for a URL:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "https://www.google.com/";
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
Process.Start(psi);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", path);
```