# Let windows decide how to open/run the file?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, io

I am saving files (images, Excel doc, Word doc, exe files, bat files and so on). I need to execute the file from inside my program and the question is if there is a way to let Windows handle how to run/execute the file? Like when you double click on a file in Explorer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ShellExecute equivalent in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258416/shellexecute-equivalent-in-net)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) method:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(myFileName)
```

Note: this will work with any registered file-extension, for example

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\Image.bmp")
```

will open the image with the registered program.

Answer (score 3):

Start new process with the saved file path name as a parameter:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathToYourFile);
```