# Launch an msi from a button using forms

Tags: c#, forms, webforms, windows-installer

I feel really silly having to ask this question as I know I should not be having so much trouble with this simple task....but I am trying to launch my .msi when a user pushes a button of a form.  I am certain this is a one liner but I cannot for the life of me figure this out.  I have the .MSI file on my desktop so I want the button to also be able to have the user select where the msi file is.  If anyone could help me that would be grand...

Comment: See this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258416/shellexecute-equivalent-in-net which basically shows the C# way of calling ShellExecute.

Comment: To see which commands you need to execute, take a look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx).

```
Process.Start("path to msi");
```

To get the path to the file, you can use the [`FileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.aspx) class (assuming winforms).

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   Process.Start(openFileDialog1.FileName);
}
```

Comment: Okay that launches the MSI :-), now what about being able to have the user select the .msi location rather than hard coding it in? Also thank you for the crazy fast response!

Comment: @Jimmy - Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1070216/jmyster) from @Jmyster, using the `FileDialog`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at using this to get the file:

```
FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog();
```