# Opening A File With Code

Tags: c#, file

I have a string of the file path and I want to open the file. Not in the way that it shows bytes in the console for example, but to open the original file with the program that suits him.

For example if my path shows a .docs file I want it to be opened with Word.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/258416/81053

Answer (score -1):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",filePath);
```